# Why would someone set primary_key=True on an One to one reationship (OneToOneField)?

Tags: django, database-design, django-orm

I was watching a video on [django-orm](/questions/tagged/django-orm) and the instructor stated that:

> We should set `primary_key=True` to prevent a Model from having duplicate rows in a OneToOne relationship (Ex: Prevent a user from having multiple profiles).

I know this statement is wrong! AFAIK, an `OneToOne` field is just a `ForeignKey` with `unique` parameter set to `True`. But I got curious and looked-up the Django documentation, Sure enough they are using `primary=True` in their example.

```
class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=80)

class Restaurant(models.Model):
    place = models.OneToOneField(
        Place,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
    )
```

So, why would someone set `primary_key=True` on an `OneToOne` relation?
My guess is that it's just reasonable to have that field as a primary key and there is no technical background behind it.

Comment: An n-ary relation(ship)/association is represented by a table with n columns. Certain binary relationships are associated with FK constraints. FK constraints get called "relationships" but they aren't.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a pattern to implement *object-oriented inheritance* in a *relational database*, for example as this [article of *Oracle* discusses](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b15901/mapping003.htm).

Indeed, it means that one can define a `Place`, and for that `Place` create a `Restaurant` model as well. It has a `OneToOneField(…)` to the "parent" model. The `OneToOneField` prevents that one can define two (or more) `Restaurant`s for the same `Place`.

Usually it is defined as a primary key, since then it shares the same "primary code space", and it removes a column that is otherwise used to do the mapping and thus would make the database larger.

Django will implement this the same way. If we define this as:

```
class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=80)

class Restaurant(Place):
    pass
```

then it will be implemented as:

```
mysql> describe place;
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int         | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name    | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| address | varchar(80) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe restaurant;
+--------------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| place_ptr_id | int  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+--------------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

It thus will add a primary key named `place_ptr_id` that refers to the `place` table. This originates from a `OneToOneField` that Django adds to the `Restaurant` model named `place_ptr`.

> We should set `primary_key=True` to prevent a Model from having duplicate rows in a OneToOne relationship (Ex: Prevent a user from having multiple profiles)

This makes no sense, since a `OneToOneField` is in essence a `ForeignKey` with [**`unique=True`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#unique). So this is already enforced by the `OneToOneField`, it is *not* necessary to make it a primary key.

Something that can not be done with the above modeling is preventing that an `Place` is a `Restaurant` and `Library` at the same time.